# My trigger is failing to create and I cant understand why

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create this trigger and I get this error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case where artcStackId = new.artcStackId' at line 7`

**Here is the failing trigger**

```
SET new.artcPublicId = 
 case 
 when new.artcCountry = 'US' then concat(91,new.artcStackId)
 when new.artcCountry = 'UK' then concat(92,new.artcStackId)
 when new.artcCountry = 'CA' then concat(93,new.artcStackId)
 else concat(11,new.artcStackId)
 end case
 where artcStackId = new.artcStackId
```

**Here is the trigger that works**

```
SET new.artcPublicId = 
case 
when new.artcCountry = 'US' then concat(91,new.artcStackId)
when new.artcCountry = 'UK' then concat(92,new.artcStackId)
when new.artcCountry = 'CA' then concat(93,new.artcStackId)
else concat(11,new.artcStackId)
end
```

when I add those extra bits, it'll fail.

Comment: are you sure of that "end case" in the first one?

Comment: What do you intend that `where` clause to **do**? Where is `artcStackId` on the left of the `=` meant to come from?

Comment: What is artcStackId in WHERE condition? Show full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reference to your where condition.i think it should be like  `where new.artcStackId = new.artcStackId`

Comment: Is that just a really convoluted way to ensure that `artcStackId` is not null? Because otherwise, if it has a value, I'm failing to see what that `WHERE` clause is bringing to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your first trigger has a syntax error:

```
end case
```

should be just

```
end
```

ie remove the trailing "case"

#### Edit:

I just noticed you have a where condition: `where artcStackId = new.artcStackId`.
You can't do that. You can only modify the current row, referenced by the `new.` syntax.

You must remove the where clause altogether, because you may only update the row being inserted/updated.

Comment: Its the same error even after I remove the case. Except now it starts at 'where'.